# Aws Event Bus Java client does not throw error when message is published to non existing eventbus

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-event-bridge

When i try to publish the event to a non existing AWS event bus, success response is 
 
received , with failedMsg count as zero

1. How to make sure we get an exception in case of wrong bus name has. been used.??

```
PutEventsRequestEntry requestEntry = new PutEventsRequestEntry();
requestEntry
        .withSource("test")
        .withDetailType("test")
        .withDetail(getJson())
        .withEventBusName("dm-outbound-event-bus-dev");

PutEventsRequest eventsRequest = new PutEventsRequest();
eventsRequest.withEntries(requestEntry);
PutEventsResult putEventsResult = amazonEventBridge.putEvents(eventsRequest);

dm-outbound-event-bus-dev -> this bus does not exist in AWS
```

Below is the Response

```
PutEventsResult {FailedEntryCount: 0,Entries: [{EventId: 5aea1a74-7557-077b-55e7-d665a555b3be,}]}
```

Library used

```
implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-eventbridge', version: '1.12.440'
```

Any Suggestion would be of great help

Comment: It's not just Java. Same happens with aws cli and boto3. Seems like the way eventbridge works(which is very confusing).